# SetNull in Python script "Value < 0"

Tags: arcpy

```
outSetNull = SetNull(outRas2, outRas2, "VALUE < 0")
```

When I try to run the SetNull tool using the expression: "VALUE < 0"

the output returns a min = 9.53674e-007

Consecutive run with exact same input:
min = -3.40282e+038

If I change the SetNull expression to "VALUE < 1"
the output returns a min = 1, as expected...

Why does the SetNull tool output this extreme negative value when expression is written as "VALUE < 0"   ?

EDIT: Here is the full script if desired

```
`import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "c:\users\lmhall\desktop\workshop"
env.overwriteOutput = True
#env.pyrmaid = "PYRAMIDS -1 BILINEAR DEFAULT"
#env.rasterStatistics = "STATISTICS"

#   check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#   script arguments
DEM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if DEM == "#" or not DEM:
    DEM = "PG_Test.tif"

Flood_Depth = int(arcpy.GetParameter(1))
if Flood_Depth == "#" or not Flood_Depth:
    Flood_Depth = "0" #Default if unspecified

Depth_Grid = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Depth_Grid == "#" or not Depth_Grid:
    Depth_Grid = "Flood_Grid.tif" #Default if unspecified

#   Process: Map Algebra(DEM - Flood_Depth)
outRas = Raster(DEM) - Flood_Depth
#Delete comment if output for outRas is desired > 
outRas.save("DEM2")

#   Process: taking the inverse of the previous output > Map Algebra (outRas * (-1))
outRas2 = -outRas
outRas2.save("DEMinv")
#   Process: Set Null for final flood depth grid output

outSetNull = SetNull(outRas2, outRas2, "VALUE < 0")
outSetNull.save(Depth_Grid)

#PyramidsIn = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#if str(PyramidsIn) == "true":
#   arcpy.BuildPyramids_management(outSetNull)
#else: PyramidsIn = "NONE"

#StatisticsIn = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
#if str(StatisticsIn) == "true":
#   arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(outSetNull)
#else: StatisticsIn = "NONE"
`
```

Comment: The number you gave above [9.53674e-007] is not a negative value it is a scientific number form of 0.000000953674. ( you can copy it to excel and re-format it to general number). So which means you have a very small positive value that is greater than zero. So setnull is doing its job properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Unfortunately I ran it again without changing a single thing and the return was

MIN: -3.40282e+038

I think I figured it out though.

Comment: I figued out that TIFF datasets cannot handle the NoData values and therefore returns the minimum value possible of the input data type.
In this case a 32-bit floating point so the extreme on the negative end would be returned.

Comment: ^ Strange, but simply returning the output in a different raster format is sufficient.
Aware that .IMG file format doesn't handle raster pyramids either.

Odd that many government organizations prefer to distribute data in *.tif and *.img format

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. if you run it without a setnull and it gave you a negative number but when you run the setnull it gives you a small positive number. It means that the setnull did it's job and set all -ve values to no data. one way to check is to do a - Con(( IsNull(data),-1,data) so that now you can set all your no data back to constant -1. The -1 values will show you all the cells the setnull function set into no data. In ArcGIS It is always recommended to do raster calculations on ESRI GRID anyway, so convert any images to that format before any spatial analysis.

Comment: Most tiff or img files come with a pre-set value to denote no data either a very large -ve number or -9999 either way that will be noted in either the metadata or the header of the raster.

Answer (score 2):

Check your scientific notation:

```
9.53674e-007 == 0.000000953674
```

(a negative e means move the decimals place to the left 7 times.)

Which is very close to 0. That's a reasonable min if you've turned everything less than 0 into null.

Comment: Ha ha we posted almost at the same time, I'll put mine as a comment :)

Comment: Valid.
However, I have been receiving extreme negative values on multiple runs of the same input settings.

MIN: -3.40282e+038

Comment: Apparently TIFFs have difficulty rendering NoData values. 
Something I never thought of...
I literally just changed the output from OutRas2.tif to OutRas2 (ESRI GRID)
It's giving me the proper output of MIN: 0

Strange.

Comment: May also be due to switching from a floating point raster(a raster format where each value is stored with a floating point number) to an integer format (where each value is stored a a whole number). When dealing with floating points you'll often see very, very small values instead of 0.  ESRI's GRID format can store either floating point or integer values.

Comment: The output raster is still a 32-bit floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a solution - but the 'Raster Analysis' settings under Environments have a setting to deal with NoData values. If the setting is set to 'Min', it defaults the NoData values to the least possible value for the raster type which is the large negative you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug in the software. SetNull is supposed to simply set all values that return True to the SQL query to the null value of the raster. Maybe it's not interpreting your integer argument in `"VALUE < 0"` correctly, given that the data is in floating point format? Maybe giving it `"VALUE < 0.0"` will make it behave?

The numbers you're getting must do with raster bit depths (see http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Bit%20depth%20capacity%20for%20raster%20dataset%20cells, especially 32-bit Floating Point - the number your first run got).

You might try using gdal_translate, a command-line tool (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). If you first reclassify all cells that meet your set-to-null criteria using ArcGIS's Reclassify (or some other tool) into a token number, say -99999, then use the gdal_translate utility to designate that value as NoData, that should work. Something like:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata -99999 inRaster.tif outRaster.tif
```